# How to search from API based on text input in REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, api, fetch-api

when i search from API based on keyword,i get all details in API.
i need get only details based on the text input from search..
i dont know the problem is in my API or My code...
please help me..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            value:'',
            value2:''                                                                                                           
        };
    this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.crimeChange=this.crimeChange.bind(this);
    this.search=this.search.bind(this);

    }
    handleChange(event){
        this.setState({value:event.target.value});
    }

    crimeChange(event) {
        this.setState({value2:event.target.value});
    }
    search(){
        let {value, value2 } =this.state;
        const url=`https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/?i=${value}&q=${value2}`;

        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET'
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json =>console.log('details',json));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <form >
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4">

                            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control" placeholder="police station">
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                                <option value="areacode">Areacode</option>
                                <option value="changaramkulam">Changaramkulam</option>
                                <option value="edakkara">Edakkara</option>
                                <option value="edavanna">Edavanna</option>
                                <option value="kadampuzha">Kadampuzha</option>
                                <option value="kalikavu">Kalikavu</option>
                                <option value="kalpakanchery">Kalpakanchery</option>
                                <option value="karipur">Karipur</option>
                                <option value="karuvarakundu">Karuvarakundu</option>
                                <option value="kolathur">Kolathur</option>
                                <option value="kondotty">Kondotty</option>
                                <option value="kottakkal">Kottakkal</option>
                                <option value="kuttippuram">Kuttippuram</option>
                                <option value="malappuram">Malappuram</option>
                                <option value="manjeri">Manjeri</option>
                                <option value="mankada">Mankada</option>
                                <option value="melattur">Melattur</option>
                                <option value="nilambur">Nilambur</option>
                                <option value="pandikkad">Pandikkad</option>
                                <option value="parapanangadi">Parapanangadi</option>
                                <option value="perinthalmanna">Perinthalmanna</option>
                                <option value="perumpadappu">Perumpadappu</option>
                                <option value="ponnani">Ponnani</option>
                                <option value="pookottumpadam">Pookkottumpadam</option>
                                <option value="pothukkal">Pothukkal</option>
                                <option value="thanur">Thanur</option>
                                <option value="thenhipalam">Thenhipalam</option>
                                <option value="thirurangadi">Thirurangadi</option>
                                <option value="tirur">Tirur</option>
                                <option value="valanchery">Valanchery</option>
                                <option value="vazhakad">Vazhakad</option>
                                <option value="vazhikadavu">Vazhikadavu</option>
                                <option value="vengara">Vengara</option>
                                <option value="vandoor">Vandoor</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <div className="form-group is-empty">
                                <input type="number" placeholder="Crime Number" className="form-control" value={this.state.value2} onChange={this.crimeChange}/>
                                <span className="material-input"></span></div>
                        </div>

                        <div className="col-md-4">
                            <button type="button" 
                            className="btn btn-primary btn-block"
                            onClick={()=> this.search()}
                            >Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Search;
```

this my api data

// 20180312234820
// https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "police station": "perinthalmanna",
    "crime number": 97,
    "details": {
      "image": "http: //asianetindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/jayanandan.jpg",
      "name": "john",
      "section of law": "IPC200",
      "type of person": "missed"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "police station": "tirur",
    "crime number": 98,
    "details": {
      "image": "https: //themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/chota-shakeel.jpg",
      "name": "mohan",
      "section of law": "Ipc407",
      "type of person": "suspects"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "police station3": "ponnani",
    "crime number": 99,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2010/10/mukhtar_ansari.jpg",
      "name": "rooney",
      "section of law": "ipc207",
      "type of person": "criminals"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "police station": "kolathur",
    "crime number": 100,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/abu_salem.jpg",
      "name": "tipper vasu",
      "section of law": "Ipc408",
      "type of person": "missed"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "police station": "kottakkal",
    "crime number": 101,
    "details": {
      "image": "https://themmindset.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/abu_salem.jpg",
      "name": "killer",
      "section of law": "Ipc402",
      "type of person": "suspected"
    }
  }
]
```

the concept is ...
if i select a policestation and crime number,then will get details based on that from API...

please help me..

Answer (score 2):

```
search(){
        let {value, value2, searchTerm } =this.state;
        const url=`https://api.myjson.com/bins/e69i9/?i=${value}&q=${value2}`;

        fetch(url,{
            method:'GET'
        }).then(response => response.json())
        .then(json =>console.log('details',json.filter(item => item["police station"].includes(searchTerm) || item["crime number"].includes(searchTerm)));
    }
```

add an input in render method

```
<input placeholder="search" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ searchTerm: e.target.value })}
```

Now you can search by id.